# How can I authorize access to a resource without knowing who I've authorized?

Tags: privacy, authorization, single-sign-on

I have a database-backed web application, with authentication via
organizational single sign-on, modeling a library lending system for
digital books. I'd like to allow users to check out books and see what
they've checked out, **without** allowing myself or other
administrators to keep track of who's checked out what. I also have a
requirement to keep stats on the number of unique users.

Ideas I've considered so far:

1. put the SSO user ID in the loan record, but clear it on return/expiry

   - pros:

     - user can get to their checkouts, even from a different device
   - cons:

     - we do have the data in the database, even if it's only while the
       book is checked out
     - unclear how to count unique users
2. instead of storing the UID, generate a random token and set it in a cookie

   - pros:

     - loans are never connected to UIDs in the database
     - can sort of count unique users, or at least browsers
   - cons:

     - users can't clear cookies or switch browsers
     - not quite counting unique users
3. hash the UID instead of using the real ID, and store the hash in the loan record

   - pros:

     - user can get to their checkouts, even from a different device
     - actual UIDs aren't connected to loans
     - can count unique users
   - cons:

     - trivial to re-hash a given UID and from that, connect users back to loans
4. make users create a password/passphrase, hash that along with the UID, and use
   that hash instead of the UID

   - pros:

     - as (3) above, plus
     - having the UID isn't enough to connect you to the loan
   - cons:

     - users won't see the value in having to do this, and will be annoyed
     - unclear how to track unique users
5. generate a one-time token, and give/email the user a URL that includes
   the token, which they have to use if they want to get back to the
   checkout. Hash that token with the UID, and use that hash as the user
   identifier in the database.

   - pros:

     - as (4) above
     - doesn’t require users to do anything
   - cons:

     - still a little rickety, possible for users to lose the URL
     - unclear how to track unique users

Is there anything better than #5? I feel like this must be a solved
security/crypto problem, but I'm blanking on the solution.

Comment: Do you or adminstrators have access to the authentication server?

Comment: @pcalkins No, we just redirect to the SSO service ([CAS](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas)) and get back a list of (mostly) LDAP attributes on a successful login.

Comment: if those attributes can't be tied to a particular user, then you're good to go.  They're effectively anonymous users.  Doesn't seem like you need anything special here.

Comment: @pcalkins The nasty bit is that I do need something tied to a particular user in order for that user to see their own particular checkouts — it's not enough to say, just authorize everyone in a particular LDAP group.